# Firebase function not works on production, from IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I do a call to Firebase function from ios/swift.

```
let functions = Functions.functions()
func callWrapper(funcName: String, data: Any? = nil) async ->  [String: Any]? {
    do {
        let result = try await functions.httpsCallable(funcName).call(data)
        return result.data as? [String : Any]
    } catch {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                let message = error.localizedDescription
                let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
            }
            //todo handle
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I got next error.

> 2023-01-05 22:29:48.821609+0200 wallpapers[41492:641302] Task
> <50374BAD-C312-450E-9770-B8300BE8FDB9>.<1> finished with error [-1007]
> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=too many HTTP redirects,
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/rejected?continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin?state%3D~AJKiYcH_jc-hcv6OubZGrM13BmNN37rWX4x6rmTm7rZ4-Lqnr9Kk2C00oVNYR97TOiJ8lcR7vP91c9rv6o89HuwIlj85hxjrj63gbmu1jzGKzkU6S_kvHXv7yGdtaOWJnImTm02c6w9igKt3PbbWcawMsOafXEizRAd8jrT0jSe704DhXZ51m8IgAKv0kXxnblLuu3-DFmm-Uvi30sCPXIRGr_XG2DrMenI-zYGRjTiXf2uBVzIom7nVmKoCxIS7dGTvQozrDisq&dsh=S-1861899242:1672950586288679&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&ifkv=AeAAQh7QjO_naDvlYC2CVX-wduN9ft7CbGKMTlrMDHmAba7cHNPiDVDd4AQJzvAJgPnBpbS7sCeK0w&rhlk=no&rrk=32,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/rejected?continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin?state%3D~AJKiYcH_jc-hcv6OubZGrM13BmNN37rWX4x6rmTm7rZ4-Lqnr9Kk2C00oVNYR97TOiJ8lcR7vP91c9rv6o89HuwIlj85hxjrj63gbmu1jzGKzkU6S_kvHXv7yGdtaOWJnImTm02c6w9igKt3PbbWcawMsOafXEizRAd8jrT0jSe704DhXZ51m8IgAKv0kXxnblLuu3-DFmm-Uvi30sCPXIRGr_XG2DrMenI-zYGRjTiXf2uBVzIom7nVmKoCxIS7dGTvQozrDisq&dsh=S-1861899242:1672950586288679&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&ifkv=AeAAQh7QjO_naDvlYC2CVX-wduN9ft7CbGKMTlrMDHmAba7cHNPiDVDd4AQJzvAJgPnBpbS7sCeK0w&rhlk=no&rrk=32,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "LocalDataTask <50374BAD-C312-450E-9770-B8300BE8FDB9>.<1>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <50374BAD-C312-450E-9770-B8300BE8FDB9>.<1>,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x6000005f7c00 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1007 "(null)"}}.

If i run on local firebase simulator, it works fine

```
functions.useEmulator(withHost: "localhost", port: 5001)
```

i assume, i call function anonymously, and this might be a problem hovewer i want to do it as anonymous unauthorized user. Is it possible somehow to allow function to be called from unauthorized user? Or how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Maybe, i have some problems with IAM permissions between firebase and gcloud. How can i diagnose it if it is a case?

Comment: Quick update:  on the nodejs backend i changed const functions = require("firebase-functions/v2"); to const functions = require("firebase-functions"); and now got error String "UNAUTHENTICATED" from swift sdk